# The diagrams of the following unary operators of temporal logic

Tags: logic, modal-logic

I am trying to learn about the following temporal operators: $X,F,G$
where $X$ is for neXt (sometimes denoted by $N$), $F$ is Future
and $G$ stands for Globally.

I believe I understand what each one means, but I am having a problem
understanding the diagrams at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_logic#Temporal_operators).

For $X$:

[image]

I am not sure about which color denotes True (they use white and red), 
but $Xp$ should be true at the next state, hwo did they say this in the diagram ?

Also (and this is a question for all $3$ diagrams): $Xp$ does not depends on if $p$ is currently true or not, so why do they sketch the truth values of $p$ above $Xp$ ?

For $F$ -

[image]

again, I don't understand how the diagram tells us what $Fp$ means.

For $G$:

[image]

This one is the most confusing, I would of expected $Gp$ to be in the same color (the one that denotes True), why some parts are white while the others are red ?

I would appriciate any help in understanding those diagrams!

Comment: P.S - I wasn't able to make the pictures render for some reason, so I put down the links. I would appriciate it if someone could kindly edit the post so the diagrams will be a part of it

Comment: Just use [the picture button](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jBwDU.png) in the toolbar, choose "From the web", and paste in the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your $Xp$ is their $Np$, for "Next, $p$."  The *red* indicates truth along that fixed $y$-coordinate. So for instance, the semantics for $Np$ state "$Np$ is true just in case $p$ is true at the next time interval." In your first diagram, $Np$ is true at 1-2, so at the next time interval (2-3), $p$ must be true. If, for example, $p$ were true at intervals 3-5 and 7-8, we'd have $Np$ being true at times 2-4 and 6-7.

$Fp$ is true just in case $p$ is true at *some* future time. So $p$ since $p$ is true at intervals 2-3 and 4-5, $Fp$ will be true up to 5. If $p$ is not true at another other intervals, then $Fp$ will not be true past 5.

$Gp$ is true just in case $p$ will be true at *all* future times. In this case, since the intervals only go up to 6, if $p$ is true from 4-6, then $Gp$ is true from 4-6. But at intervals 1-4, $p$ isn't *always* true at *all* future times, so $Gp$ isn't true.

Comment: This was very helpful, thanks Alex!